# How reparameterize Beta distribution?

Tags: distributions, beta-distribution

$\newcommand{\Beta}{\operatorname{Beta}}$Consider $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma)$; I can reparameterize it by $X = \varepsilon\mu + \sigma; \varepsilon \sim N(0,I) $

But given Beta distribution $X \sim \Beta(\alpha,\beta)$; is there easy way (closed form transformation) to reparameterize $X$ with some very simple random variable (Normal, uniform )

My major goal is to do VAE such that my prior is Beta and my posterior is also Beta; so I'm thinking how to reparameterization trick for Beta. What I want to do, is instead of directly sampling from $\Beta(\alpha,\beta)$ (because couldn't do backpropagation), I want first generate $\varepsilon \sim \mathcal{Q}$ some easily sampled distribution, then apply some deterministic function that involves $\alpha, \beta$, such that after the transformation it follows $\Beta(\alpha,\beta)$.

Comment: Why do you want to reparametrize it?

Answer (score 5):

There is always the obvious inverse cdf representation:
$$X=F_{\alpha,\beta}^{-1}(U)$$
where $F_{\alpha,\beta}^{-1}(\cdot)$ is the inverse cdf (quantile function) of the Beta $\mathcal Be(\alpha,\beta)$ distribution.

Otherwise, the Wikipedia page lists a large collection of connections with other standard distributions, like the Gamma and the F distributions. For integer valued $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the Beta $\mathcal Be(\alpha,\beta)$ distribution is the distribution of an order statistic of a Uniform sample.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply; I feel I didn't make the post clear. My major goal is to do VAE such that my prior is Beta and my posterior is also Beta; so I'm thinking how to reparameterization trick for Beta

Comment: @ElleryL this is what the answer seems to suggest: that you can generate $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{U}(0, 1)$ and then just pass it through the inverse cumulative distribution function of beta $X = F^{-1}_{\alpha,\beta}(\epsilon)$, that is a deterministic function.

Comment: @Tim; thanks for the help; so I guess the trick would be using  Kumaraswamy to approximate the inverse of CDF Beta as mentioned https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51820/fast-approximation-to-inverse-beta-cdf. here as my deterministic function ?

Answer (score 4):

<s>If you mean representing every beta-distributed random variable as some simple function of the two parameters $\alpha,\beta$ and some "standard beta" random variable, then probably it cannot be done.</s>

One alternative to the simple standard way of parameterizing this family of distributions that has crossed my mind is as follows.

The expected value is $\mu=\dfrac\alpha{\alpha+\beta}.$

The variance is $\dfrac{\frac\alpha{\alpha+\beta} \cdot \frac\beta{\alpha+\beta}}{\alpha+\beta+1} = \dfrac{\mu(1-\mu)}{\alpha+\beta+1} = \dfrac{\mu(1-\mu)}\kappa$

where the last equality defines $\kappa.$

So we have
\begin{align}
\mu & = \alpha/(\alpha+\beta), \\
\kappa & = \alpha+\beta+1. \\[12pt]
\alpha & = (\kappa-1)\mu, \\
\beta & = (\kappa-1)(1-\mu).
\end{align}
$\mu$ is the mean and $\kappa$ is the concentration. With $\mu$ fixed, $\kappa$ is proportional to the reciprocal of the variance.

**Postscript:** It has occurred to me that what I said in the first paragraph above is mistaken, and I've crossed it out. One can use the beta distribution with $\alpha=\beta=1,$ which is the same as the uniform distribution on $[0,1].$ If $X$ has that distribution, then $F^{-1}(X)\sim\operatorname{Beta}(\alpha,\beta),$ where $F$ is the c.d.f. of the $\operatorname{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ distribution.

**Postpostscript:** The postscript above does not represent an alternative parametrization of the family of beta distributions, since the same pair of parameters still represents the same distribution.

Comment: Hi; thanks for the reply. But I get little confused here. Consider I have $\alpha, \beta$; and I want to a sample from $Beta(\alpha,\beta)$. Instead of directly sample from $Beta(\alpha,\beta)$ (because couldn't do backpropagation), I first generate $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{Q}$ some easily sampled distribution, then apply some deterministic from involves $\alpha, \beta$ such that the transformed follows $Beta(\alpha,\beta)$. But how do I proceed the similar approach here with your parameterization ?

Comment: @ElleryL : It has occurred to me that what you ask can be done, but it would not have occurred to me to called it a reparametrization of the beta distribution. I've added a postscript to my answer explaining that.